# Groupby + mean function producing e numbers which don't look right

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have the following code where I am trying to group the dataframe 'newdata' by the first column and then find the mean of the column '0_happy'.

However, the output is producing me with e numbers, which seem too big/small to be mean values.

I would be so grateful if anybody could point out where I may be going wrong?

```
newdatahappy = newdata.groupby(newdata.iloc[:,0])[str(0) + '_happy'].mean()

print(newdatahappy)

0_type
fullMiss    3.113534e+20
hit         1.893626e+07
nearMiss    4.149066e+13
Name: 0_happy, dtype: float64
```

The first 10 rows of newdata:

```
        0_type 0_happy 0_motive
0        NaN     NaN      NaN
1        NaN     NaN      NaN
2        NaN     NaN      NaN
3        NaN     NaN      NaN
4        NaN     NaN      NaN
5   fullMiss      37       66
6   nearMiss      33       67
7        hit      75       60
8   fullMiss      36       63
9        hit      74       42
10  nearMiss      19       45
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to test your code on the first 10 entries. As expected it seems to work fine.
I would suggest using it like with the column. Like this:

```
# to make it easier for other folks trying to check this out
NaN = np.nan
data = [[NaN,NaN,NaN],
[NaN,NaN,NaN],
[NaN,NaN,NaN],
[NaN,NaN,NaN],
[NaN,NaN,NaN],
["fullMiss",37,66],
["nearMiss",33,67],
["hit",75,60],
["fullMiss",36,63],
["hit",74,42],
["nearMiss",19,45]]
newdata = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['0_type', '0_happy', '0_motive'])

# you can use the column name directly in groupy
newdata.groupby("0_type")[str(0) + '_happy'].mean()
```

But that shouldn't affect the results.

You could also use a pivot table like this:

```
newdata.pivot_table(index='0_type', values='0_happy',aggfunc="mean")
```

Result:

```
0_type
fullMiss    36.5
hit         74.5
nearMiss    26.0
Name: 0_happy, dtype: float64
```

Anyway, I would suggest you check your actual input data to check you don't have extreme outliers for example.

To start, check the maximum values for example:

```
newdata.pivot_table(index='0_type', values='0_happy',aggfunc="max")
```

Comment: When I check for extreme outliers using the maximum values:

0_type          
fullMiss       8
hit           75
nearMiss      59 - thus it doesn't seem like there are outliers. Do you think it could be to do with 'NaN' values? :)

Comment: I have now found a solution - thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: @Caledonian26 that’s great! you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

change your `float format` option

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format
```

Comment: I don't think that the problem is in the display/format. I believe the problem are the values.

Comment: @Panda Kim thank you for the suggestion - sadly the issue is still there :(

Comment: @D.Manasreh what do you think might be wrong with the values? :)

Comment: @D.Manasreh I have now found a solution - thank you so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution by first converting the values in the '0_happy' column to 'int' values before grouping, and then calculated the mean.

```
newdatahappy = newdata.groupby(newdata.iloc[:,0])[str(0) + '_happy'].mean()
newdata[str(j) + '_happy'] = newdata[str(j) + '_happy'].astype('int')
```

Thank you so much for all your help! :)